# SQLAlchemy Inserting Data in a Many-to-Many Relationship with Association Table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, associations

I've seen a few questions similar to this but none quite hit the nail on the head. Essentially I have three table models `Center()`, `Business()`, and `CenterBusiness()` in a Flask Application using SQLAlchemy. Currently I'm adding to said relationship in this manner:

```
biz = Business(typId=form.type.data, name=form.name.data,
               contact=form.contact.data, phone=form.phone.data)
db.session.add(biz)
db.session.commit()

assoc = CenterBusiness(bizId=biz.id, cenId=session['center'])
db.session.add(assoc)
db.session.commit()
```

As you can see that's a bit ugly and I know there is a way to do it in one hit with the relationship as they are defined. I see on SQLAlchemy's docs they have a explanation of working with such a table but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
#Directly from SQLAlchemy Docs
p = Parent()
a = Association(extra_data="some data")
a.child = Child()
p.children.append(a)

#My Version Using my Tables
center = Center.query.get(session['center']
assoc = CenterBusiness()
assoc.business = Business(typId=form.type.data, name=form.name.data,
                          contact=form.contact.data, phone=form.phone.data)
center.businesses.append(assoc)
db.session.commit()
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be doing the trick... Any help would be greatly appreciated and below I've posted the models involved.

```
class Center(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(MEDIUMINT(8, unsigned=True), primary_key=True,
                   autoincrement=False)
    phone = db.Column(VARCHAR(10), nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=False)
    businesses = db.relationship('CenterBusiness', lazy='dynamic')
    employees = db.relationship('CenterEmployee', lazy='dynamic')

class Business(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(MEDIUMINT(8, unsigned=True), primary_key=True,
                   autoincrement=True)
    typId = db.Column(TINYINT(2, unsigned=True),
                      db.ForeignKey('biz_type.id',
                                    onupdate='RESTRICT',
                                    ondelete='RESTRICT'),
                      nullable=False)
    type = db.relationship('BizType', backref='businesses',
                           lazy='subquery')
    name = db.Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=False)
    contact = db.Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(VARCHAR(10), nullable=False)
    documents = db.relationship('Document', backref='business',
                                lazy='dynamic')

class CenterBusiness(db.Model):
    cenId = db.Column(MEDIUMINT(8, unsigned=True),
                      db.ForeignKey('center.id',
                                    onupdate='RESTRICT',
                                    ondelete='RESTRICT'),
                      primary_key=True)
    bizId = db.Column(MEDIUMINT(8, unsigned=True),
                      db.ForeignKey('business.id',
                                    onupdate='RESTRICT',
                                    ondelete='RESTRICT'),
                      primary_key=True)
    info = db.relationship('Business', backref='centers',
                           lazy='joined')
    archived = db.Column(TINYINT(1, unsigned=True), nullable=False,
                         server_default='0')
```

Comment: What exactly is happening? Is there an error? Is the state of the database not what you expect it to be?

Comment: When I run the code as shown in the example and read the queries it seems to be doing most of what it's supposed to. But I never see an insert statement, only selects and then a rollback with no immediate defined reason.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but you can [configure the relationships so you don't need to work with the join tables directly](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many). `children = relationship('Child', secondary=association_table)`

Comment: @dirn That is perfect for a many to many but does not include a true table with Association Objects as far as I understand.

Comment: You're right. You actually want the [Association Object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) section. `children = relationship('Association', back_populates='parent')`

Comment: @dirn which I'm using in Center minus the back populates or backref (almost interchangeable) as I have no need for bidirectional access. However, you can see under the Center model (parent) the attribute businesses (children) which relates to the CenterBusiness table.

Comment: Alright my issue was that I was not using the relationship key "info" I have in my `CenterBusiness` model to define the appended association. I was saying `center.business` thinking that the term `business` in that case was arbitrary. However, I needed to actually reference that relationship. As such, the appropriate key I had setup already in `CenterBusiness` was `info`. Updating my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working, my problem lied in the following bit of code (error in bold):

```
#My Version Using my Tables
center = Center.query.get(session['center']
assoc = CenterBusiness()
**assoc.info** = Business(typId=form.type.data, name=form.name.data,
                          contact=form.contact.data, phone=form.phone.data)
center.businesses.append(assoc)
db.session.commit()
```

As explained in my comment in the question:

> Alright my issue was that I was not using the relationship key "info"
>   I have in my CenterBusiness model to define the appended association.
>   I was saying center.business thinking that the term business in that
>   case was arbitrary. However, I needed to actually reference that
>   relationship. As such, the appropriate key I had setup already in
>   CenterBusiness was info.

I will still accept any updates and/or better ways to handle this situation, though I think this is the best route at the time.

Answer (score 0):

below example can help u
more details http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html

```
class User(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'user'
     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = Column(String(64))

     # association proxy of "user_keywords" collection
     # to "keyword" attribute
     keywords = association_proxy('user_keywords', 'keyword')

     def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name

class UserKeyword(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'user_keyword'
     user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
     keyword_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('keyword.id'), primary_key=True)
     special_key = Column(String(50))

      # bidirectional attribute/collection of "user"/"user_keywords"
      user = relationship(User,
            backref=backref("user_keywords",
                            cascade="all, delete-orphan")
        )

    # reference to the "Keyword" object
    keyword = relationship("Keyword")

    def __init__(self, keyword=None, user=None, special_key=None):
        self.user = user
        self.keyword = keyword
        self.special_key = special_key

class Keyword(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'keyword'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   keyword = Column('keyword', String(64))

  def __init__(self, keyword):
      self.keyword = keyword

  def __repr__(self):
       return 'Keyword(%s)' % repr(self.keyword)
```

Comment: Okay, I see what you were saying... So what is the benefit of using `association_proxy` vs `relationship`? Can you access the associated table for other functuons as well? (IE: to query and/or filter)

Comment: it will help you in query operation. you can access other attribute of association table.

Comment: You can do that with relationship, I'm trying to more clearly understand the difference? Does it maintain a direct key in the returned object? Or does it also return as an object in the returned object?